# How to plot Q-Q plot of Exp versus Weibull in R

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have a random sample $X$ of size $500$ from an $Exp(1000)$ distribution. I assume that $\lambda =0.2$ and I convert $X$ into $Y$ by the Box-Cox transfoamrtion $y(\lambda )=\frac{x^{\lambda}-1}{\lambda}$. I want to plot the Q-Q plot of the sample $Y$ versus Weibull distribution $Weib(5,1000)$ in R as follows:

[image]

The figure comes from a paper.

**What I've tried:**

```
    set.seed(123)
    x <- rexp(500, 1000)
    lambda <- 0.2
    y <- (x ^ lambda - 1) / lambda
    z <- rweibull(500,5,1000)
```

There is a problem when I put ${\rm qqplot(z,y)}$. I would be grateful if someone could help about that.

Comment: Most of your $x$ values are much less than $1$ so most of your $y$ values are negative, and I would have thought would not come from a [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) which unfortunately has three different parametrisations, though all with non-negative support

Comment: That being said, you almost get a straight line with `qqplot(z,y)` but the scale and location are clearly different.  Personally I might have considered something like `z <- qweibull(ppoints(500),5,1000)` for the theoretical quantiles

Comment: @Henry Thank you very much for your comments and your help. I got it. It works. Could you please tell me how I can plot the black straight line in the figure? I mean "qqline()" here.

Comment: I do not understand `qqline` but you will find something like `abline(-5, 1/800)` puts a line on your chart - you may want to adjust its parameters

Comment: Maybe try https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Aruralreader Sure. Appriate it.

Comment: @Henry Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some r code that qqplots

1. *Empirical quantiles* of the Cox-Box transform of a sample of i.i.d. exponential distribution with scale = $1000$ vs the theoretical quantiles of the Weibull distribution with parameter shape =5, scale = 1000
2. The Cox-Box transformed quantiles of the exponential distribution with $\lambda=1000$ vs the theoretical quantiles of the Weibull distribution with parameter shape =5, scale = 1000

> ```
> ### Cox-Box transform
> cox_box <- function(y,lambda =0.2){
>       (y^lambda -1)/lambda
>     }
>     
> y <- rexp(1000,1000) # sample
> ylambda <- cox_box(y) # transformed sample
>     
> p <- seq(0,.999, by = 0.001)
> w <- qweibull(p,5,1000) # theoretical quantiles Weibull
> yq <- qexp(p,1000)      # theoretical quantiles Exponential
> yq_lambda <- cox_box(yq) # transformed quantiles
>     
> qqplot(ylambda,w)
> lines(yq_lambda,w, col = 'blue')
>     
> qqplot(yq_lambda,w)
> lines(yq_lambda,w, col = 'blue')
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice exaplnation and the codes.